# how to use datename expression with case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select Case When (DATENAME(dw, cm.Hearing_Date) as DayName) ='Tuesday' 
Then 'मंगलवार' from xyz;
```

Comment: What is your question and what you are trying to achieve? Add some more details to your question. Your syntax is wrong for case when then it should be `case...when....then...end`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your CASE syntax and might use the simple version (assuming you want to return other weekdays, too):

```
select
   Case DATENAME(dw, cm.Hearing_Date)
     When 'Monday' Then 'सोमवार' -- sometimes translate.google is helpful :-) 
     When 'Tuesday' Then 'मंगलवार' 
     ... 
   end as DayName
from xyz;
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be:

```
select Case When DATENAME(dw, cm.Hearing_Date)  ='Tuesday' Then 'मंगलवार' end as DayName 
from xyz;
```